# Cannot access Django Model from Celery in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, celery

I've been working on this problem most of the day and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am building an application with django and I started messing around with deploying it to docker and using celery to schedule tasks. I have celery running a custom manage.py command using call_command once per minute. Everything is working! Except I cannot seem to access django models from my custom django admin command. I have tried to import the model inside my function, and also use get_model to no avail. When I do Model.objects.all() the query is always empty. When I try to grab a specific Object with Mode.objects.get(id=##) it gives me an error. The command works perfectly when I call it using docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec web python manage.py [custom-command] but not when run by celery. Hopefully, someone out there knows of a fix because From when I have read so far it seems like this should be working. Alright, enough talking here is some code.

**Here is my docker-compose file for celery**

```
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A [appname] worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - SECRET_KEY=[secret-key]
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
    depends_on:
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A [appname] beat -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - SECRET_KEY=[secret-key]
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

**Here is my celery.py**

```
import os, [appname]

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[appname].settings")

app = Celery("[appname]")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**Here is my tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.management import call_command

@shared_task
def some_function():
    call_command("[command-name]", )
```

TLDR; Custom Django Admin Command cannot access django models when being run as a scheduled task using Celery

I hope someone has encountered this before. Cheers!